# Why do file copies on Windows 7 appear to stop towards the end of the process?

Tags: windows-7

Assume the following:

1. I have a 20 GB test file that I copy to a USB 3-based Flash drive
2. The file copy process is steady for around 99% of the upload, but the process of the last remaining part of the file appears to stop for around 5 minutes

Why does this happen? I've seen this on both Flash and disk-based drives on Win 7 on multiple different hardware configurations.

Comment: Because the GUI doesn't show the actual copy process to the target drive, but RAM buffering. When it appears to be stalled it actually is still writting to thee target.